# When did non-SI double prefixes go out of use?

Tags: terminology, units

In old physics and engineering publications from the 1950s or so, it's common to see non-SI "double prefixes", such as a "millimicrosecond pulse", or a "10 micromicrofarad" capacitor.

These units are considered obsolete today. However, I failed to find a historical review on the use of these units.

- In which year did units like "nano-" and "pico-" become parts the SI-standard?
- When did the use of standard SI-prefix become common and largely replaced the "double prefixes" in engineering?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Resolution 12](https://www.bipm.org/en/CGPM/db/11/12/) of the 11th Conférence Générale des Poids et Mesures (CGPM) adopted 12 SI prefixes in 1960, including pico- and nano-. Google Ngrams show steep decline in the use of [millimicro-](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=millimicro&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmillimicro%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmillimicro%3B%2Cc0) after 1964, and [micromicro-](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=micromicro&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmicromicro%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmicromicro%3B%2Cc1) after 1966. Some other [double prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix#Double_prefixes), like kilomega- and hectokilo- were also in use, decimilli- was even standardized in Frace until 1961.